# Counting within a list. Help me understand this code

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I found a [3 year old question that helps me count the number of occurrences of variables within a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088062/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-number-in-a-list/9088528#9088528). The question  had the answer below. The code works. But I can't understand how, can someone help me make sense of this?

Here is the answer with the code I found, writing in quotation marks is part of the answer:

```
count([],X,0). 
count([X|T],X,Y):- count(T,X,Z), Y is 1+Z.
count([X1|T],X,Z):- X1\=X,count(T,X,Z).
```

'However note that the second argument X is supposed to be instantiated. So e.g. count([2,23,3,45,23,44,-20],23,C) will unify C with 2. If you want the count for every element use'

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

count([],X,0).
count([X|T],X,Y):- count(T,X,Z), Y is 1+Z.
count([X1|T],X,Z):- X1\=X,count(T,X,Z)

countall(List,X,C) :-
   sort(List,List1),
   member(X,List1),
   count(List,X,C).
```

'Then you get'

```
 ?- countall([2,23,3,45,23,44,-20],X,Y).
   X = -20,
   Y = 1  ;
   X = 2,
   Y = 1 ;
   X = 3,
   Y = 1  ;
   X = 23,
   Y = 2  ;
   X = 44,
   Y = 1  ;
   X = 45,
   Y = 1  ;
   no
```

I am very new to Prolog, I only understand one part of this code, and it is this

```
sort(List,List1),
member(X,List1),
```

I would appreciate an explanation of this the whole thing, especially how Y is being printed.

Comment: Have not got time to explain it all now, but `trace.` is your friend. Type that then execute the goal `countall(...)`. Each time you press "redo" (`;`) it is retrying another possibility of `count`. `Y` is being printed because you asked prolog to resolve `Y` in the goal you gave it... Hope this helps!

Comment: This is an interesting, maybe, but not an easy question, since there is no clear answer. I will not downvote or vote to close but you should maybe try to ask a more specific question. At the moment, a complete answer would be something like a tutorial covering most Prolog basics as unification, negation, backtracking, multiple solutions, the "top level" (the REPL), etc.

Comment: maybe the point you're missing could be that sort/2 *removes* duplicates ?

Comment: @Boris I mainly just want to understand how it is counting and keeping track of the variables, I can make sense of the rest.

Comment: @BretC Thank you about mentioning trace, that did help me make more sense of the code, although I keep getting errors such as  _G4017, and creep. Also I understand why X is being printed, because of member function, but still don't understand how Y is.

Comment: @CapelliC I've understood that. I came across msort while looking around on the internet, but that only seems to sort it up to 9 variables before stopping and giving ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About counting, first try to think about the *meaning* of the code.

```
list_member_occ([], _, 0).       % list is empty, 0 occurrences
list_member_occ([X|Xs], X, N) :- % list has the element at the head
    list_member_occ(Xs, X, N0),  % count number of elements in the tail
    succ(N0, N).                 % the number of occurrences is the
                                 % next natural number
list_member_occ([Y|Xs], X, N) :-
    dif(X, Y),                   % head and the element are different
    list_member_occ(Xs, X, N).   % occurrences in the tail of the list
                                 % is the total number
```

In this code, `succ(N0, N)` is (arguably) a better way to say "`N` is the natural number after `N0`" than `N is N0 + 1`. One reason is that [`succ/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=succ/2) was meant to be used in every direction:

```
?- succ(2, 3).
true.

?- succ(X, 4).
X = 3.

?- succ(1, X).
X = 2.
```

... while [`is/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28is%29/2) *should* be used with unbound left operand. Take this query

```
?- list_member_occ([1,1,2,1], X, 3).
```

... for an example of `N` being a number instead of a free variable.

Using the predicate:

```
?- list_member_occ([1,2,1], X, N).
X = 1,
N = 2 ;
X = 2,
N = 1 ;
N = 0,
dif(X, 1),
dif(X, 2),
dif(X, 1).
```

One interesting property of [`dif/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=dif/2), as opposed to `\=/2`, is that it imposes a constraint on the variable `X` in the last solution: `X` cannot, from now on, take any of the values `1`, or `2`.

For the reason why you get all answers using `dif/2`, consider:

```
?- X = Y. % unify X and Y and succeed
X = Y.

?- X \= Y. % succeed if you cannot unify X and Y
false.

?- dif(X, Y). % succeed if X and Y are and will be different
dif(X, Y).
```

When you use `X \= Y`, Prolog tries to unify its arguments and **fails if the unification succeeds**. This means that you only get the solution in which all free variables have been unified to each other, but you miss solutions where free variables are different from each other.

About the `Y = ...`, when you make a query at the top level, it reports to you all new variable bindings that were made during successful proofs of this query. As the most simple example:

> Which numbers are between 3 and 5, both including?

```
?- between(3, 5, X).
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5.
```

You don't need, of course, to print out the values of `X` by hand; just type a semicolon to get the next answer. After the last answer you get a full stop and return to the `?-` prompt.

About the sorting: it sorts the whole list, but only *shows* you the first 9 elements of the sorted list. See [this FAQ page from SWI-Prolog](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html). In a nutshell, the easiest is to type `; true` after your query, to make sure that there is at least one choice point, and use `w` and `p` to switch between showing the whole term and only some of it.

```
?- string_chars("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", Cs), sort(Cs, S) ; true.
Cs = [t, h, e, ' ', q, u, i, c, k|...],
S = [' ', a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h|...] [write]
Cs = [t, h, e, ' ', q, u, i, c, k, ' ', b, r, o, w, n, ' ', f, o, x, ' ', j, u, m, p, s, ' ', o, v, e, r, ' ', t, h, e, ' ', l, a, z, y, ' ', d, o, g],
S = [' ', a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z] .

?- string_chars("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", Cs), sort(Cs, S) ; true.
Cs = [t, h, e, ' ', q, u, i, c, k, ' ', b, r, o, w, n, ' ', f, o, x, ' ', j, u, m, p, s, ' ', o, v, e, r, ' ', t, h, e, ' ', l, a, z, y, ' ', d, o, g],
S = [' ', a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z] [print]
Cs = [t, h, e, ' ', q, u, i, c, k|...],
S = [' ', a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h|...] .
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why don't you elaborate a bit on the beauty of your definition of `count/3`? In particular, the answers to `count([1,2,3],X,Y)`?

Comment: @Boris Thank you, your comments are very helpful. Regarding the original code, where it says Y is 1+Z, how does it make sure Z starts of as 0, (or Y).

Comment: @Boris How different is your use of succ(N0, N) to the original 'Y is 1+Z'.

Comment: @Boris What does Succ do?

Comment: @false yes, this was probably necessary.

Comment: @FProlog I tried to be a bit more explicit about the meaning of the code above. Note how simply using `succ/2` instead of general arithmetic makes the predicate more useful.