# Prolog How to count all element?

Tags: prolog

[Count the number of occurrences of a number in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088062/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-number-in-a-list)

I am trying to understand those codes.

```
count( []     , X , 0 ) .
count( [X|T]  , X , Y ) :- count(T,X,Z), Y is 1+Z .
count( [X1|T] , X , Z ) :- X1 \= X, count(T,X,Z) .
    
countall( List , X , C ) :-
  sort(List,List1) ,
  member(X,List1) ,
  count(List,X,C) .
```

How can I write a helper function to get everything in one line?

```
?- countall([2,23,3,45,23,44,-20],X,Y).
X = -20,
Y = 1 ? ;
X = 2,
Y = 1 ? ;
X = 3,
Y = 1 ? ;
X = 23,
Y = 2 ? ;
X = 44,
Y = 1 ? ;
X = 45,
Y = 1 ? ;
```

I am expecting to `newL` to be `[-20,1],[2,1],[3,1],[23,2],[44,1],[45,1]`.

I wrote

```
getAll(L,newL) :- countall(L,X,C) , newL =[X,C] .
```

How do I store everything and get it in one time?

Is it I have to do the tail recursion for `getAll`? Or I should rewrite `countall`, replce `member` to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you describe is something like this. First, a public predicate, `frequencies/2`. Breaking it down clause-by-clause:

1. The empty list has the empty list as its set of frequency pairs:

   ```
   frequencies( [] , [] ).
   ```
2. For a non-empty list, we (1) sort the list, keeping duplicates — `sort/2` sorts the list and removes duplicates, make the list a *set*, whilst `msort/2` does not remove duplicates — and (2) invoke the helper predicate `freqs/4` passing it the *tail* of the source list and seeding its additional state with the *head* of the source list and an initial frequency count of `1`:

   ```
   frequencies( [X|Xs] , Fs ) :- msort(Xs,X1), freqs(Xs,X,1,Fs) .
   ```

That gives us:

```
frequencies( []     , [] ) .
frequencies( [X|Xs] , Fs ) :- msort(Xs,X1), freqs(Xs,X,1,Fs) .
```

And then we need our helper predicate, `freqs/4`. Clause-by-clause:

1. If the source list is exhausted, our additional state (`Y` and `N`) represent the current pair. Just move them to the result list and you're done:

   ```
   freqs( [] , Y , N , [Y,N] ) .
   ```
2. Otherwise, if the head of the source list matches the current element `Y`, add 1 to the frequence count `N` and recurse down on the tail of the source list:

   ```
   freqs( [X|Xs] , Y , N , Fs ) :- X  = Y, N1 is N+1, freqs(Xs,Y,N1,Fs).
   ```
3. Finally, if the head of the source list does not match the current element, move the current tuple `[Y,N]` to the result list, set the current element with an initial frequency of `1`, and recurse down:

   ```
   freqs( [X|Xs] , Y , N , [[Y,N]|Fs] ) :- X \= Y,            freqs(Xs,N,1,Fs).
   ```

Putting that all together, you get

```
freqs( []     , Y , N , [Y,N]      ) .
freqs( [X|Xs] , Y , N , Fs         ) :- X  = Y, N1 is N+1, freqs(Xs,Y,N1,Fs).
freqs( [X|Xs] , Y , N , [[Y,N]|Fs] ) :- X \= Y,            freqs(Xs,N,1,Fs).
```

And the whole thing, then is

```
frequencies( []     , [] ) .
frequencies( [X|Xs] , Fs ) :- msort(Xs,X1), freqs(Xs,X,1,Fs) .

freqs( []     , Y , N , [Y,N]      ) .
freqs( [X|Xs] , Y , N , Fs         ) :- X  = Y, N1 is N+1, freqs(Xs,Y,N1,Fs).
freqs( [X|Xs] , Y , N , [[Y,N]|Fs] ) :- X \= Y,            freqs(Xs,N,1,Fs).
```

We can make some improvements, though, to eliminate unnecessary backtracking: if the `X = Y` test in the second clause of `freqs/4` succeeds, backtracking into the 3rd clause will fail (because `X = Y` and `X \= Y` cannot both be true.) We can reorder clauses 2 and 3 and introduce a *cut* (`!/0`) thus:

```
frequencies( []     , [] ) .
frequencies( [X|Xs] , Fs ) :- msort(Xs,X1), freqs(Xs,X,1,Fs) .

freqs( []     , Y , N , [Y,N]      ) .
freqs( [X|Xs] , Y , N , [[Y,N]|Fs] ) :- X \= Y, !,         freqs(Xs,N,1,Fs).
freqs( [X|Xs] , X , N , Fs         ) :-         N1 is N+1, freqs(Xs,Y,N1,Fs).
```